# Is "coincident" followed with "as" or "with"?

Tags: prepositions, licensing

I was looking at [examples of the word usage of](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/coincident) "coincident", and I saw that most "coincidents" were followed by "with".

[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coincident?s=t) then says that coincident is "happening at the same time", so rather than "with", is following "coincident" with "as" also acceptable?

For example:

Coincident **with/as** the cutting of the tree, the edge of the axe dulled.

Which one would be the correct/common way of following "coincident" with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Coincident* + *as* is as far as I know meaningless.

Perhaps *as* in your question is a typo for *at*. *Coincident* + *at* is possible, but it means something different than *coincident* + *with*.

- The object of *with* in this case is an entity which occupies the same literal or figurative location as the entity which *coincident* modifies
- The object of *at* in this case would be the location where the coincidence takes place.

Words develop many relationships like this more by historical accident than by any underlying semantic "logic". Some tendencies are observed, but they have no predictive value. It is particularly hopeless to predict what prepositions a specific word will "license" in what sense by comparison of words with a similar meaning. I'm afraid you just have to learn these connections one at a time.